# In bash script, setting an environment variable where the env variable name is in a bash variable

Tags: bash

In a bash script, if I have a variable $FOO which equals "BAR", how would I set the environment variable *named* BAR equal to "BAZ"?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `export BAR="BAZ"`?

Comment: Evidently it's simply $FOO=BAZ but it wasn't working for me because my variable was an array entry.  I'll get the array entry value into a scalar and then I should be good.  Thanks.

Comment: with simpy $FOO=BAZ got: BAR=BAZ: command not found. ` export $FOO=BAZ ` did the job, though it also exports.

Answer (score 2):

`export $(echo "$(echo $FOO)=BAZ")` should work.  I'm using bash --version = 4.1.2 with success.

```
export FOO=BAR
export $(echo "$(echo $FOO)=BAZ")
echo $BAR
```

BAZ

Comment: just

`
export $FOO=BAZ
`

did the job too,